# Arduino IDE/ESP8266: Why does a button have to be pressed twice to get the correct output?

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266

I have been teaching myself about programming the ESP8226, specifically the ESP8226-12F. I have this script based on an online example:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

WiFiServer server(80); //Initialize the server on Port 80

void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); //Our ESP8266-12E is an AccessPoint
  WiFi.begin("***","***"); // Provide the (SSID, password);
  Serial.begin(115200); //Start communication between the ESP8266-12E and the monitor window
  IPAddress HTTPS_ServerIP= WiFi.localIP(); // Obtain the IP of the Server
  Serial.print("Server IP is: "); // Print the IP to the monitor window
  Serial.println(HTTPS_ServerIP);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin(); // Start the HTTP Server
}

void loop() {
  String status;
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Somebody has connected :)");
  //Read what the browser has sent into a String class and print the request to the monitor
  String request = client.readString();
  Serial.println(request);
  // Handle the Request
  if (request.indexOf("/CLOSE") != -1) {
    Serial.println(request.indexOf("/CLOSE"));
    status = "CLOSED";
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OPEN") != -1) {
    Serial.println(request.indexOf("/OPEN"));
    status = "OPEN";
  }
  Serial.println(status);
  // The HTML
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
  s += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
  s += "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\"   content=\"default-src 'self'\"> <meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"no-referrer\" /></head><body>";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"b1\" value=\"OPEN DOOR\" onclick=\"javascript:location.href='/OPEN'\">";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"b2\" value=\"CLOSE DOOR\" onclick=\"javascript:location.href='/CLOSE'\">";
  if(status == "OPEN") {
    s+= "<br><br><p>OPEN</p>";
  } else {
    s+= "<br><br><p>CLOSED</p>";
  }
  s += "</body></html>\n";
  client.flush(); //clear previous info in the stream
  client.print(s); // Send the response to the client
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
```

You'll see that the initial HTTP response creates two buttons: OPEN DOOR and CLOSE DOOR.

The issue I am having is that the CLOSE button has to be pressed twice in order for the sketch to output "CLOSED".

Here's the output from the Serial Monitor.

1: First time browse to http://10.0.1.92:

```
Somebody has connected :)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.92
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive

Client disonnected
```

2: Press Open Button http://10.0.1.92/OPEN and "OPEN" is displayed

```
Somebody has connected :)
GET /OPEN HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.92
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://10.0.1.92/


4  // This is value of request.indexOf("/CLOSE")
OPEN
Client disonnected
```

3: Press CLOSE http://10.0.1.92/CLOSE and "OPEN" is still displayed

```
Somebody has connected :)
GET /CLOSE HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.92
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://10.0.1.92/OPEN


4 
371 // No idea where this comes from
OPEN
Client disonnected
```

4: Press CLOSE the second time and "CLOSED" is displayed:

```
Somebody has connected :)
GET /CLOSE HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.92
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://10.0.1.92/CLOSE


4
CLOSED
Client disonnected
```

Why does the CLOSE button have to be pressed twice to get "CLOSED" to display? Is this a logic issue, or an HTTP issue, or some combination of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was these statements:

```
if (request.indexOf("/CLOSE") != -1){  . . .
if (request.indexOf("/OPEN") != -1){  . . .
```

If you look at the the response strings you can see that those if statements were matching the GET /OPEN or GET /CLOSED  AND the Referer: http://10.0.1.92/CLOSE and Referer: http://10.0.1.92/OPEN.

That 371 I didn't understand at first was the string position of the /OPEN in Referer: http://10.0.1.92/OPEN. That match was flipping status back to OPEN until the Referer changed and producing the observed behavior.

I changed the if statements to include a space so that there would only be a match for the GET /CLOSE or GET /OPEN, i.e.

```
if (request.indexOf(" /CLOSE") != -1){  . . .
if (request.indexOf(" /OPEN") != -1){  . . .
```

and it works as it should. So, there was nothing wrong with the logic, it was doing exactly what it should have done ;).

Thanks to JLH for his or her help.

Answer (score 0):

This is suspicious:

```
if(status == "OPEN"){
   s+= "<br><br><p>"+status+"</p>";
} else {
   s+= "<br><br><p>"+status+"</p>";
}
```

What's the `if` statement for if both alternatives are the same?

Also `Referer` shows three different values when, based on your design, one would expect two.  I wonder where you are initially setting the state of this binary state machine?

EDIT:

So OP has updated source code.

```
if(status == "OPEN") {
    s+= "<br><br><p>OPEN</p>";
  } else {
    s+= "<br><br><p>CLOSED</p>";
  }
```

Versus:

```
 if (request.indexOf("/CLOSE") != -1) {
    Serial.println(request.indexOf("/CLOSE"));
    status = "CLOSED";
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OPEN") != -1) {
    Serial.println(request.indexOf("/OPEN"));
    status = "OPEN";
  }
```

Do you see how those are logically different now?

This probably means that when the state machine starts, since it's not open, it is CLOSED in the top block but not CLOSED in the bottom.  Next button press changes it to open, and then the second changes it to closed?  Could this be what's happening?

Comment: Oy, bad case of tunnel vision on my part. That should be `if(status == "OPEN"){
  s+= "<br><br><p>OPEN</p>";
} else {
  s+= "<br><br><p>CLOSED</p>";
}` Does not fix the issue though.

Comment: Ok so please update your question.  Next step, since this is essentially a two-state (binary) finite state machine, what is the initial state?  I can't see where you're setting its initial state.  Lack of an initial state can cause weird behavior in state machines.

Comment: The state is set the first time one of the buttons is pushed. That initial state could be closed or open depending on which button is pushed first.

Comment: So it's a three-state state machine, with the first state being "undefined."  This is not an ideal design.  Better to have an initial state, always.

Comment: I can't run your code now, but please see my latest edit to my answer.  The "default" CLOSED condition based on the `else` block makes me suspect the three-state-two-state thing is still the problem.